# Incoming phone call handling

Tags: android

This is familiar problem. I am writing a media player application. I want to pause my media player when there is a incoming call. How can i do that. Already done with my SMS handling with following code.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter= new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        SMSReceiver sMSReceiver= new SMSReceiver();
        registerReceiver(sMSReceiver, intentFilter);
```

So is there any simple way to handle incoming calls also

Answer (score 1):

Use `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` and `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`. Check the intent for:

```
intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
```

which should equal one of these.

In your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write one Broadcast receiver and declared it in manifest

```
   <receiver
        android:name="com.sample.myapp.ReceiveIncomingCall"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

write a Receiver like this...

```
public class ReceiveIncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            // call is coming...
        }
    }
}
```

and add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

You should properly handle audio focus. There is a good guide on Android Developers: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html

```
OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    if (focusChange == AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT
        // Pause playback
    } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
        // Resume playback 
    } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
        am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
        am.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
        // Stop playback
    }
};
```